# How do I find my way home?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm lost. Like really lost. And it is late. And I don't know where I live or how to get there from where I am.

Is there a map I can use to find my way home?

Comment: Without the tag, this is slightly unnerving. D:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by default, <kbd>M</kbd> is the shortcut key for the map. Alternatively you can hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and fourth tab is the Map.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. It's obvious I don't play a lot of PC stuff

Comment: You can also use the mouse on the map to hover over various buildings and it'll give you a little tooltip showing information about the building (like opening hours for stores). This is especially handy when starting out and you haven't memorized where everything is yet.

Comment: @FAE Note that this only works for buildings you have been too. You will see "???" over places you have not been. (Which is helpful in its own right.) And in addition you are shown in your "exact" position. It is not a grid based system. If you in the bottom left of a zone, you're sprite appears in the bottom left area of that zone (as opposed to a game like Pokemon where you can only see that you are in a city or Route and not where in the city or the route).